# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not projective using the Hom functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

I am aware of more direct proofs of this on this website but I am looking for a proof along the following lines:

Find an epimorphism $f:A \to B$ such that $Hom(\mathbb{Q},A) \to Hom(\mathbb{Q},B)$ is not an epimorphism. Therefore the above Hom functor is not exact and $\mathbb{Q}$ is not projective. I am thinking that I should use the fact that $Hom(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is continuing from Lord Shark's answer. You might not be satisfied with this proof because you have to choose... Nonetheless...,

Proof: Choose a generating set $S$ for $\mathbb Q$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module (for example $S = \mathbb Q$ works, but there are (I think) smaller sets you can choose). Take $A$ to be the free abelian group with $\mathbb Z$-basis $S$, so $A \cong \bigoplus_{s \in S} \mathbb Z$, and take $B = \mathbb Q$; since $S$ generates $\mathbb Q$, there is an surjective $\mathbb Z$-module homomorphism $A \to \mathbb Q$. Now $$Hom(\mathbb Q, A) \cong Hom(\mathbb Q, \bigoplus_{s\in S}\mathbb Z) \cong \bigoplus_{s \in S}Hom(\mathbb Q, \mathbb Z) = \bigoplus_{s \in S} 0 = 0$$ where the second isomorphism is from a basic fact that $Hom(-, -)$ commutes with direct sums in the second slot; and the second to last equality is by the fact OP stated.

On the other hand $Hom(\mathbb Q, \mathbb Q) \neq 0$ since it contains the identity map for example. $\square$

Comment: Thanks. I am okay with choosing (I am not a constructivist :) ). I thank that a smaller generating set for Q is $\{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: Yeah that set works, with $n \neq 0$. Also I think $\{1/p : p \text{ prime}\} \cup \{1\}$ may work too.

Comment: @cat $\{1/p\}$ for $p$ prime does **not** work.

Comment: Is $1/4$ in the group generated by the $1/p$, $p$ prime?

Comment: Ah! how silly of me... So we would need all $1/p^n$ for $p$ prime and $n \in \mathbb N$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can take $A$ to be a free Abelian group and $B$ to be $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I can't think of an epimorphism from a free abelian group to $\mathbb{Q}$. Do you mean an infinitely generated one?

Comment: @edenstar Yes$\phantom{}$