# When does Hom functor commutes with direct sum in the second slot

Tags: modules, direct-sum

I have seen in a post that there is a basic fact for R-modules and the morphisms:
$$\operatorname{Hom}(A,\bigoplus_{i\in I}B_i)\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I}\operatorname{Hom}(A,B_i)$$

I only know that it is true when replacing both direct sums by direct products, which is obvious by the universal property of product. It is also obvious by the property of coproduct that the direct sum of the first slot can be moved outside to be direct product. While this one does not seem to be that obvious.

Does this hold in general? If so, can someone provide an easy proof? I've seen a similar one about group representation but that is rather confusing to me.

Comment: This is false in the infinite case, no?

Comment: I am not sure. But here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2342589/prove-that-mathbbq-is-not-projective-using-the-hom-functor) it says this is true for infinite case.

Comment: Well IF that is correct, maybe it is because the rationals are in the first slot.  That doesn’t make it true generally.

Comment: Someone just told that this require $A$ to be finitely represented. Else let $A$ be the infinite direct sum as $B_i$ and $id_A$ in the left has no corresponding in the right.